# What does a fractional colour bit depth mean?

Tags: bit-depth

Looking at camera comparison sites today, I encountered statements like "color depth: 23.5 bits".

(See [here](http://snapsort.com/compare/Canon-EOS-5D-Mark-III-vs-Nikon_D7000/detailed) for example, which gives the 5D Mk III a 24-bit colour depth, and the D7000 a 23.5 bit colour depth).

My usual understanding is that in a [24-bit colour representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth#True_color_.2824-bit.29), there are 8 bits per channel (i.e. 8 bits for each of the red, green and blue channels). Given that a bit is indivisible, how do I interpret a fractional bit depth? It this just somebody taking `log2(max-color-value)`** and forgetting to round/truncate, or is it meaningful in terms of hardware or image encoding (or something else)?

** e.g. if the actual sensor colour space is smaller than a 24-bit RGB colour space, and then the effective depth is `log2` of that. But the pixels are 14-bit in most high-end cameras, so this doesn't make sense either...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Snapsort is using [DxOMark](https://www.dxomark.com/) for its sensor data, and DxOMark explain [here](https://www.dxomark.com/About/Sensor-scores/Use-Case-Scores) what each of their scores mean. Specifically for Color Depth, they say:

> Maximum color sensitivity reports, in bits, the number of colors that the sensor is able to distinguish.

i.e. DxOMark claim that the 5D Mark III can distinguish 2^24 = 16.8 million colours, while the D7000 can distinguish 2^23.5 = 11.9 million colours. Don't worry too much about the absolute numbers, all it means is that the 5D Mark III can distinguish about √2 times as many colours as the D7000, at least by DxOMark's metrics (which they don't make public).

Comment: Congrat's on 10k :)